# OpenCV using Mat to modify video pixel value and merging back

Tags: mat

Hi really hope someone could help me out with this, been stuck for quite awhile. After the changing the pixel value of blue at x = 100, y = 200 and merging back as fin_vid.

The value doesn't seems to be the same as what I wanted when I read back from the fin_vid.

There is something wrong with my merging but I don't understand why.

```
 split(frame, rgb);

 Mat fin_vid, tmp;

 namedWindow("blue",1);

 imshow("Original Video", frame); 

 imshow("blue", rgb[0]);


       if (waitKey(30) == 27) //wait for 'esc' key press for 30 ms. If 'esc' key is    pressed, break loop
       {
               cout << "esc key is pressed by user" << endl; 
               break; 
       }
       rgb[0].convertTo(tmp, CV_8UC1);
    for(int j = 0; j<ModText.size(); j++)
    {

        for(int k = 0; k<8; k++)
        {

            int blue = (int)tmp.at<uchar>(hx+j,wy+k);


                cout<<blue<<endl;          
           if (blue%2==1)
           {
            if ( ary[j][k]== 48){                   
                blue = blue - 1;
            }
           }            
            else if( ary[j][k] == 49) {
                    blue =  blue + 1;
            }

tmp.at<uchar>(hx+j,wy+k)=blue;

cout << "the new value of the pixel is " << (int)(tmp.at<uchar>(hx+j,wy+k)) << endl;}               

vector<Mat> channels;

channels.push_back(tmp);

channels.push_back(rgb[1]);

channels.push_back(rgb[2]);

merge(channels, fin_vid);

namedWindow("B",1);imshow("B", fin_vid);

namedWindow("watermarked video");

imshow("watermarked video", fin_vid);

outputVideo.write(fin_vid);


}
```

Comment: A tip is to use a debugger to see at what point the value is changing into something you don't want.

Comment: I did, still unable to understand what's going on. I removed splitting and merge. Still the same